# function inside function is not waiting for promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, loopback

Sorry if my title is not very explicit I dont know how to explain this properly.
I am trying to use the distinct function for my app that uses loopback 3 and mongodb. It seems to work right but my endpoint wont hit the return inside my function.
This is my code

```
const distinctUsers = await  sellerCollection.distinct('userId',{
      hostId : host.id,
      eventId:{
        "$ne" : eventId
      }
    }, async function (err, userIds) {;

      if(!userIds || userIds.length ==0)
        return [];

      const filter = {
        where:{
          id: {
            inq: userIds
          }
        }
      };
      console.log("should be last")
      return await BPUser.find(filter);
    });
    console.log(distinctUsers);
    console.log("wtf??");
    //return [];
```

If I uncomment the return [] it will send the return and later it will show the should be last, so even when I dont have the return it seems to finish. It is now waiting for the response.  I dont like the way my code looks so any pointer of how to make this look better I will take it.

Comment: What exactly is that `sellerCollection` thing? If it does not expect an `async` function, stuff probably won't work.

Comment: `sellerCollection.distinct` is highly unlikely to take a node-style asyncrhonous callback AND return a Promise - very rare to see something like that - also, you have a stray `;` in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `sellerCollection.distinct` takes a callback as one of it's parameters, therefore, you **cannot** use `async/await` with a callback-style function, since it's not a promise.

I would suggest turning this call into a promise if you'd like to use `async/await`:

```js
function findDistinct(hostId, eventId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sellerCollection.distinct(
      'userId', 
      { hostId, eventId: { "$ne": eventId } },
      function (error, userIds) {
        if (error) { 
          reject(error); 
          return; 
        }
        if (!userIds || userIds.length === 0) {
          resolve([]);
          return;
        }
        resolve(userIds);
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Then, you can use this new function with `async/await` like such:

```js
async function getDistinctUsers() {
  try {
    const hostId = ...
    const eventId = ...

    const distinctUsers = await findDistinct(hostId, eventId)

    if (distinctUsers.length === 0) {
      return
    }

    const filter = {
      where: {
        id: { inq: userIds }
      }
    }
    const bpUsers = await BPUser.find(filter) // assuming it's a promise

    console.log(bpUsers)
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I thought this would work but  it still seems like what ever happens on the secondary function seems to run on a another thread idk. I did this     console.log("a1");
    const distinctUsers = await findDistinct (sellerCollection, host.id, eventId);
    console.log({"aaa": distinctUsers});
And it doesnt pass to the second console.log.

Comment: @JuanDiego I just realized I made a mistake in the `findDistinct` function, sorry, please try again with the changes that I made